# How does a SqlConnection knows that it is executed in a TransactionScope

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, transactionscope

For a project I'm writing a bunch of queries, which are in it's own separately, but they need to be executed in a transaction.

I'm using a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Consider the following code:

```
// connection = new SqlConnection(...); 
// connection.Open();

using(var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // execute first query on connection
    using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE THIS", connection))
    {
        // sqlCommand.Parameters....
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // second query
    using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT THAT", connection))
    {
        // sqlCommand.Parameters....
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Now how does the `sqlCommand` know that somewhere in previous code I have a `transactionScope`?

Comment: The link in your question has the answer to your question. And transaction is not the TransactionScope you created.

Comment: @Blam is right. Here is the text _Upon instantiating a TransactionScope by the new statement, the transaction manager determines which transaction to participate in. Once determined, the scope always participates in that transaction._

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  Answer: In this code example, the `SqlCommand` does **not** know it belongs to the `TransactionScope`, and actually will **not** execute within the transaction.  Declaring a `TransactionScope` does not automatically initiate a transaction on the connection.  Rather, the `SqlConnection` is designed to automatically "enlist" itself in the `TransactionScope`, but _only if it is opened within that scope_.  To use `TransactionScope` with a `SqlConnection`, you would typically open the scope, then open the DB connection, then execute the SQL commands.

Comment: If the connection was already open outside the scope, you can still manually bind the connection to the `TransactionScope` by calling `connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)`.  Relevant documentation is in the article for Distributed Transactions (ADO.NET).